# How to make a responsive canvas element within a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a canvas within a div tag. I need to make the width and height of the canvas such that it matches with the width and height of the div. How to do this?

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 p-0" id="mycanvasdiv" style="background-color:blue">
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Following makes it fixed

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
```

Following does not work

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" height="100%" width="100%"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just add this:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 p-0" id="mycanvasdiv" style="background-color:blue">
    <canvas id="mycanvas" style="width: 100%; height:100%;"></canvas>
</div>
```